# Files mismatch работает в eclipse, не работает в repl.it

Tags: java, eclipse

Есть метод для сравнения содержимого двух файлов, в eclipse всё корректно работает, а в repl.it ошибка, как исправить?

```
    public static void equal() throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("first file name: ");
        String firstFile = sc.nextLine();
        File firstFileSize = new File(firstFile);
        if (!firstFileSize.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Does not exist");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("second file name: ");
        String secondFile = sc.nextLine();
        File secondFileSize = new File(secondFile);
        if (!secondFileSize.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Does not exist");
            return;
        }
        Path pathFirstFile = Paths.get(firstFile);
        Path pathSecondFile = Paths.get(secondFile);
        if (sameContent(pathFirstFile, pathSecondFile) == true) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }

    }

    private static boolean sameContent(Path file1, Path file2) throws IOException {
        return Files.mismatch(file1, file2) == -1;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очевидно какой-нибудь пакет не импортирован

Comment: В eclipse работает, просто копирую код в repl.it все пакеты есть.

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

Comment: какая версия java установлена в repl.it?

Comment: @Grundy 
(build 11.0+6+10-post-Ubuntu)
Пробовал создавать файл .replit : language = "java12"
run = "javac *.java && java Main"
но всё равно не работает.

Comment: @Grundy не знаете как исправить?

Comment: По всей видимости пока поддерживается только 11 версия java